# Sequentially Compact implies Compact?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness, first-countable

I know that in metric spaces sequentially compact is equivalent to compact. I also know that compact and sequentially compact for general topologies there is no relation between them. But I wanted to know if there is the same implication for Hausdorff I-countable spaces. The only thing I have found is that for Hausdorff spaces with the B-W property implies countably compact.

Any books where I can research more on the subject?

Comment: I am not sure, but Wilanski's Topology for Analysis has  a large collection of tables indicating which properties of topological spaces imply/don't imply which other properties.

Comment: What is the B-W property?

Comment: What is I-countable?

Comment: @PaulFrost I believe B-W property is the Bolazano-Weirstrass property: every infinite subset has a limit point.

Comment: @Ulli I believe by _'I-countable'_ OP meant first countable.

Comment: @feynhat: yes, this was also my first thought. But the OP should be aware that it's not our task to *guess*, what he means by some completely uncommon notations.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first time. Next time I will write in a better way, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Even better, you can click on the Edit button and improve the text of your question right now to explain what you mean by I-countable and B-W.  Otherwise future readers will remain very confused.  (check wikipedia to see if the terminology is standard or not)

Answer (score 1):

The [$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/) may be a good place to start your search. For example, [this search](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=First%20Countable%2BCompact%2B%7ESequentially%20Compact) reveals that all compact first-countable spaces are sequentially compact, while [this search](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=First%20Countable%2B%7ECompact%2BSequentially%20Compact) shows examples of first countable sequentially compact spaces that fail to be compact.